# year coming wrong in TO_DATE function in db2

Tags: database, db2

I tried to run below query in DB2 database:

My date string: 122887  mmddyy
select DATE(TO_DATE('122887', 'mmddyy')) from SYSIBM.dual;

now result is: 2087-12-28

But i am expecting below 1987-12-28.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the "[adjusted year](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007107.html)" for your query. Instead of YY it is RR:

```
values(DATE(TO_DATE('122887', 'mmddrr')))"

1         
----------
12/28/1987
```

Details are in the [documentation for TO_DATE/TIMESTAMP_FORMAT](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007107.html).

Comment: In postgresql, I am using select to_date(substring('0303653597' from 0 for 7),'DDMMYY')--gives me 2065-03-03, I want it 1965...